# How to handle game flow?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I'm developing a simple game and I am trying to separate the Updating of the View from the calculations and game state.
I've tried to make a `Game` class that would handle actions and reactions and updating the logical state of the game.
The interaction between this class and the View is really a mess since they are lots of actions to handle and for each action many view parts that must be updated.

Sometimes the changes to the view are the same in multiple code parts.

What is the best way to handle game states in XAML/C# or is this a good way to handle game states?

Comment: Could the observer pattern be what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm reading about it right now I'll let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the observer pattern

When a change happens update the model.  Each element of the game should be represented in the model as a object.  The view should have objects that change depending on objects in the model.  These are the observers.  You register all the observers with what they observe when you build them (I think c# calls these delegates though you're free to build your own observation system)

When an observed object in the model changes state it marks itself as having changed and loops through every observer from the view that registered with it.  It tells them all about the change.  The viewer objects turn around and request whatever state info from the observed object that they care about.

If you've never written one by hand yourself you really should do it once.  It takes a lot of the mystery out of it.  People make it sound more complicated than it really is.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would have done:

Let the View update itself, it has to repaint **n** frames per second right? The view will interact with the models, not the other way around. The View will not care whether the models are updated, it will simply take the needed data from them and repaint accordingly each frame.

Comment: It's not a high framerate game, it's kind of a cards/classic game